# Marriage without the consent of father?

Tags: halal-haram, nikah, consent

Is a woman of age 25 allowed in Islam to marry without her father's consent? Father is alive and not abusive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If he refuses the marriage and there is no Islamic reason for him to refuse it, she can seek a new Wali.

For example, the person you want to marry is good. Then you can do such thing by going to the closest Male relative, the imam if there is none, the Judge/Magistrate if there are none, and finally the ruler (Caliphate) if there are non in the chain.

In Islam, there is something called Refusal of the parent to marry their daughters with those they want `العضل`, which is forbidden in Islam. In Such cases, the ruler/Imam/Judge will order the parent to revert on their stance (same with those who commit Zina/Drink Wine) and if they refused, the Imam/Judge/Ruler can marry them without his permission.

Fatwa: https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/71740