# If a girl is not a virgin, can nikah be valid without a wali?

Tags: nikah, wali, consent

Me and my girlfriend want to get married but our parents will never agree just because I'm a Sunni and she is Shia.  We really want to get married and not be involved in haram.

If a girl is not a virgin, can nikah be valid without a wali?

Comment: Relevant http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/29089/can-my-husband-ask-my-hand-from-my-uncle-not-my-dad, http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/114/is-a-marriage-valid-without-presence-consent-of-anyone-else?rq=1 and http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/26237/marriage-without-the-consent-of-father

Comment: If she is shia, than she can marry without parent's consent, http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/260/15642 . But, it is just validity of nikah, other than that, you should actually try to convince your parents. At-least try. And even though, being in relationship of a GF and BF is already haraam what you are doing. Even without being physical or anything, it is still haraam. But its good you are trying to turn it to halal.

Comment: I would have tried asking my parents but they already told earlier if i fall in love with a girl and she is not sunni and if i wanna be with her i should forget that i ever had a home. And her case is worse then this

Comment: What about her family

Comment: Are you sure you guys will be happy in such relation? I have seem a lot of such relations that end terribly.

Comment: "our parents will never agree"... Muslim parents and parents in law always claim to be harsher than what they really are. In my experience, this kind of opposition is never eternal. If you really want to marry her, insist (or even do it without them), and they will change eventually their mind.

Comment: @ZiaUlRehmanMughal it is said by the link: For example for a virgin girl the permission of her father is needed but not his presence necessarily.

Comment: i think, wali (of bride) must be present in nikah, but his agreement is not necessary if she is not virgin. see my answer in http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/18809/marriage-without-parents-consent

Comment: i have more full answer in http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/23774/is-marriage-without-a-wali-for-a-divorcee-woman-valid

Answer (score -3):

Parents consent in such matters is necessary because finding a suitable girl/boy for their son/daughter is an obligatory duty upon them. Therefore Prophet Mohammad has said: "To whoever is born a child, the child should be given a good name and sound education. And when he 
becomes of age he should be married" (hadith).

The only way to marry her is to convert her to Sunni Islam. In this way, you will get married with her and your parents will have no objection.

Comment: Salaams and welcome to Islam Stack Exchange. Please note that we are a pluralistic site; whether you agree with them or not, any posts which imply that followers of any flavour of Islam "are not true Muslims" are completely unwelcome here.